# Converting negative voltage to positive

Tags: power-supply, power, converter, atx

I am adding an ATX power supply as a bench power supply to power accessories on my model railroad layout. I prefer to run some lighting accessories at +7v, but obviously a power supply has +3.3v, +5v, +12v and -12v. Someone said getting +7v was as simple as wiring a +5v to a -12v wire. That didn't seem right to me. Is it, and if not, what would I need to use to convert the -12v to positive voltage?

Comment: They probably meant the +12 to +5v wires, since that gives 7v.  This is an old trick for fans, although it isn't necessarily safe for other devices.

Answer (score 1):

Between the +5V and the -12V outputs, you have a total of 17V, definitely not what you need. Connecting the two together will damage the power supply. Not good either.

The proper way to get +7V is to use a buck regulator to regulate the +12V down to +7V with good efficiency. This is usually easier than to convert from a negative voltage.

The Alibaba web site is choke-full of buck converters of various current ratings that would certainly work just fine.

If your current demand is low (a fraction of an ampere), a linear regulator may work but they tend to get hot unless they are heat sunk. A Buck regulator is easier to implement.

You may need to read in general about buck regulators to understand how they work and apply them effectively.

Comment: Lighting, switch machines, etc aren't current hogs. A step down voltage regulator it is then. Thanks.